# is this something we can write or just say

Tags: register, greetings, run-on-sentences

Is the sentence below run on or is it something we say to each other

Isn't "Have a great morning/night" a run-on sentence? or can I say "you have a great morning/night"? Or is that just a sentence we say.

Comment: What makes you think that it might be a run-on sentence? Here is a definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have a great morning / night.

is not something that would usually be written, but more often said.
Both your sentences have the same meaning, but when written one might use

> Hope you have a good morning / night.